# Manage TStringList who is send at TcpServer New Connections

Tags: delphi, indy, tcpserver

i have a question.
Actually i send a TStringList as TStringStream for every new connection on TcpServer using code:

```
ConCli.DBS := TStringStream.Create;
Database.SaveToStream(ConCli.DBS);
ConCli.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(Format('%d', [ConCli.DBS.Size])));
ConCli.Connection.IOHandler.Write(ConCli.DBS);
ConCli.DBS.Free;
```

That's works perfectly, but i have a question.
and if i need manage Database TStringList?, example if i need delete/increase some item while a new connection comes and TcpServer try send it, can that cause some fault? how fight against that?

What i think is, create another instance of TStringList, Assign the Database at this new TStringList, manage new TStringList and then Clear Database TStringList and Assign it again. That's wrong? have a better way for do that?

Thanks.

Actually Code:

```
ConCli.DBS := TStringStream.Create;
Database.SaveToStream(ConCli.DBS);
ConCli.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(Format('%d', [ConCli.DBS.Size])));
ConCli.Connection.IOHandler.Write(ConCli.DBS);
ConCli.DBS.Free;
```

What i think on do:

```
var
PreList: TStringList;
begin
PreList := TStringList.Create;
PreList.Assign(Database);
//Manage Pre List like delete items/add
Database.Clear;
Database.Assign(PreList);
PreList.Free;
```

that's wrong? have a better way for do?

---

I did some tests, and now i understand the problem (Please correct me if i did something wrong).

i Created NoSafeList as TStringList, added 2 items "a" and "b".
Then i created that code who created 10 threads where access DefaultList Items at same time:

```
var
  x : Integer;
begin
  for x := 0 to 10 do
  begin
    TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      while True do
      begin
        try
          Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Thread %d - DefaultList Content: %s', [TThread.CurrentThread.Handle, NoSafeList.Text]));
        except
          on E: Exception do
          begin
            Memo1.Lines.Add(E.Message)
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end).Start;
  end;
```

this code cause program freeze/crash in 5 seconds or less.

then i created Database as TIdThreadSafeStringList, and same, added 2 items "a" and "b" and again same code where create 10 threads who access database items and that's works PERFECTLY without problems, i just see the memory of program always increase, what can be the problem for that?

```
var
  x : Integer;
begin
  for x := 0 to 10 do
  begin
    TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      List : TStringList;
    begin
      while True do
      begin
        List := Database.Lock;
        try
          Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Thread %d - DataBase (Safe) Content: %s', [TThread.CurrentThread.Handle, List.Text]));
        finally
          Database.Unlock;
        end;
      end;
    end).Start;
  end;
```

Comment: It appears you are using Indy's `TIdTCPServer`. Note that its client connections operate in worker threads, so any resources you want to share across thread boundaries, like your `Database`, or a centralized `TStringList`, will need to be adequately protected from concurrent access by multiple threads. For instance, using `TCriticalSection`, `TIdThreadSafeStringList`, etc

Comment: I did both tests here using TStringList (No Safe) and TIThreadSafeStringList and worked like a charm, also edited post with the code, just answer me about memory please.

Comment: You cannot access the UI in a thread. You must `Synchronize(` or `Queue(` the `Memo1.Lines.Add(`.

Comment: That isn't the question here, the question is access TStringList on Tcpserver.
also on tests, it worked using CritLock.Acquire;
        try
          Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Thread %d - NoSafeList Content: %s', [TThread.CurrentThread.Handle, NoSafeList.Text]));
        finally
          CritLock.Release;
        end; 
too

Comment: The unsafe UI access in threads  invalidates the test. Fix that. As for the memory, you are continuously adding new strings to the UI, so of course memory usage is going to increase, why would you think it wouldn't?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Use TCriticalSection for lock/release the multiple access to Database don't make any problem at system? example the second connection didn't receive the database because system was busy with lock from first connection thread?

Comment: @LuizFelipe the second thread will simply be blocked waiting its turn to acquire the lock until the first thread unlocks it. So make sure you always unlock it if you successfully lock it, or else the second (and subsequent) thread(s) will wait forever.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Right, and the TCriticalSection should be declared as Global right?

Comment: @LuizFelipe it does not need to be global (and many people will argue that globals should be avoided), just place it somewhere that both threads can reach it, preferably next to the `Database` itself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i access it at IdTCPServer1Connect only, so can declare it on him instead Global? and final question, if i need manage Database outside thread (manual change) i need declare again local TCriticalSection and lock/release right? this second TCriticalSection also will lock the database at IdTcpServer1Connect? or for that need be global?

Comment: @LuizFelipe You could make the `Database` and `TCriticalSection` be members of the Form that owns the `TIdTCPServer`, for instance. And yes, you must always lock/unlock it, in all threads that want to access it. But DO NOT use a second `TCriticalSection`, that defeats the whole purpose. All access to `Database` would need to go through a *single* `TCriticalSection`.